# Why does this condition check the expectation?

Tags: algorithms, divisibility, integers

Let's suppose `n` as an Integer.
Let's suppose `i` as an Integer.

To check whether the given `i` is higher than the largest multiple of n that fits in a 32-bit Int, we can do (from a book about programming):

```
IF(i + (n - 1) - (i % n) < 0) THEN i is higher than the largest multiple of n.
```

Nothing more is explained in the book.

I don't figure out why this instruction does the job...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say this is more likely a programming question than a mathematical one. $i + (n-1) - (i \mod n)$ should, under normal circumstances, just return the next multiple of $n$ that comes after $i$. But if that value is larger than the largest possible int, then it will overflow and return a negative value (essentially, this is all wrapped in the implicit modulus operation that occurs when overflows are treated by wrapping values back around).

Comment: i = 12, n = 7.  =>  12 + 6 - 5 = 13, not 14 ....

Comment: I don't figure out what the `(n-1)` means.

Comment: You're right, it actually takes you to the number *before* the next multiple of n. i - (i mod n) is the largest multiple of n less than i, so adding (n-1) gets you to one less than the next multiple. So if kn < i < INTMAX < (k+1)n, then the expression returns (k+1)n - 1 which is almost always going to overflow, although I *think* that the test actually fails if i = INTMAX and i mod n = 1, but I'm not sure.